# NodeJS Express Routing With Multiple URI/URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, middleware

I have a public folder inside my app which contains the HTML/CSS3/JS code.It has 2 part to it. One contains the public facing index.html inside public/web and another is the admin view which contain is only for admins. Below is the basic layout

```
public
     -->admins-->app/index.html
     -->web-->multi-page-layout-->webuild/index.html



app.use('/admin/login/system', gzippo.staticGzip("public/admins/app"));
app.use('/', gzippo.staticGzip('public/web/multi-page-layout/webuild'));
```

My problem is the base route `/` works as expected. but when I access `/admin/login/system` the page throws an error as `CSS/JS` files linked using `script` and `link` are not found.

Below is one of the error message generated in console

```
 http://localhost:5001/admin/login/plugins/moment.min.js
```

Attached screenshot for reference [image]

How can I create route so that I can access these pages and the pages should work fine and expected. Please note all are AngularJS app in different folder and using EJS is not feasible.

How can I fix the route so that the route `/admin/login/system` is loaded and so is its reference files from its index.html

Attaching reference of my folder structure

[image]

Comment: What do the links look like in your HTML pages to .js files and .css files?  Do they start with a `/`.  Any link that you want to be served from `public/web/multi-page-layout/webuild` should start with a leading `/` so it's not relative to the browser page's URL.  Then, the browser will request the same URL for the resource whether you're in an admin page or a regular page.  If it doesn't start with a `/`, then it will be a page relative link and the browser will add the path of the current web page to the URL before requesting it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to configure your server to serve your Angular app entry point. So you have one server defined route and since you are using Angular, client-side routing should kick in for navigating to other pages(this is assuming you have such routings implemented in your angular app and your app is an SPA)